# "Impressions of" or "Impressions on"?

Tags: prepositions

I am writing an essay. Should the title be "Impressions on drug usage in developing countries" or "Impressions of drug usage in developing countries"?
In the essay, I am highlighting the people's perception on drug usage.

Comment: I think "Impressions of drug usage in developing countries" will be more apt. This means the impressions are about the drug usage, not on the drug usage.

Comment: I would recommend a more descriptive title.  _Drug usage_ (even assuming you mean harmful drugs only)  can mean either 'statistics on the usage of drugs' or 'actual drug usage' , so "impressions of drug usage" could be your personal report from using drugs, or it could be a report on a change in statistical reporting practices. If you don't want the reader to be disappointed, be clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you say "impressions of" the reader will probably think you are talking about other people's perceptions.  If you say "impressions on" people will probably think you are talking about your own impressions.

Frankly I would not use *impressions* in this title.  How about

> Perceptions of drug usage in developing countries

Answer (score 0):

I think "Impressions of drug usage in developing countries" will be more apt. This means the impressions are about the drug usage in developing countries. There is no impression on the drug usage.

The impression is on the countries, not on drug usage. I hope you understand.

Comment: Please expand upon your answer. *Impress* means to make an imprint upon (either physical or mental). We can either make an imprint on something or take (also have) that imprint from something. Which way the imprinting goes will dictate which preposition we choose.